# Getting Syntax Error while launching RIDE

Tags: automated-testing, test-automation-framework, robotframework, keyword-driven, ride

I have installed Robot Framework, as well as wxPython 2.8.12.1. After I installed RIDE, and launch RIDE by executing ride.py, I am getting the following error:

```
C:\Python27\Scripts>ride.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\robotide\__init__.py", line 83, in main
    _run(inpath, not noupdatecheck, debug_console)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\robotide\__init__.py", line 102, in _run
    from robotide.application import RIDE
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\robotide\application\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .application import RIDE, Project
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\robotide\application\application.py", line 22, in <module>
    from robotide.namespace import Namespace
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\robotide\namespace\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .namespace import Namespace
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\robotide\namespace\namespace.py", line 31, in <module>
    from robotide.publish import PUBLISHER, RideSettingsChanged, RideLogMessage
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\robotide\publish\__init__.py", line 123, in <module>
    from .messages import *
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\robotide\publish\messages.py", line 21, in <module>
    from .messages2 import *
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\robotide\publish\messages2.py", line 24, in <module>
    from robotide.publish import publisher
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\robotide\publish\publisher.py", line 24, in <module>
    from pubsub import pub
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pubsub\pub.py", line 146
    def getDefaultPublisher() -> Publisher:
                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

These are the versions I am using:

```
Pillow==5.4.1
Pygments==2.3.1
Pypubsub==4.0.0
pywin32==224
robotframework==3.1.1
robotframework-ride==1.7.3.1
robotframeworklexer==1.1
six==1.12.0
typing==3.6.6
wxPython==4.0.4
```

Also, I installed wxPython 2.8.12.1, yet I am getting the wxPython version as 4.0.4 as mentioned above.

I am not getting the problem. Does anybody have any solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42140876/theres-invalid-syntax-in-pub-py) the latest version of Pypupsub that is compatible with Python 2.X is `3.3.0`. You have `Pypubsub==4.0.0`. Try to downgrade pypubsub version.

Comment: Thanks. I downgraded pypubsub to 3.3.0 and it solved the problem.